# Child view controllers view doesn't fit parent's view on iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using child view controllers for presenting various states in my scene. I have: LoadingViewController, FailureViewController and TableViewController for each state.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func add(_ child: UIViewController) {
        addChild(child)
        view.addSubview(child.view)
        child.didMove(toParent: self)
    }

    func remove() {
        guard parent != nil else {
            return
        }
        willMove(toParent: nil)
        removeFromParent()
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

My problem is, that the child controllers view doesn't fit the parent's view entirely on the iPhone X (other devices are just fine). Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try adding explicit frame to subview, i.e.

```
func add(_ child: UIViewController) {
    addChild(child)
    child.view.frame = (your expected frame)
    view.addSubview(child.view)
    child.didMove(toParent: self)
}
```

Comment: `child.view.frame = view.bounds` works as expected. feel so stupid, thank you